# Does Elasticsearch aggregations over 10k documents require Scroll API?

Tags: elasticsearch, scroll

I have an index in elasticsearch with more that 10k documents in it.
My question is in order to perform aggregations all of the documents in the index, do I need to use **Scroll API** and then aggregate the sub results ? Or does elastic aggr operations can work over all of the documents in entire index without issues.

Answer (score 5):

The Scroll API is useful **if and only if** you need to paginate over your documents.

If all you need to do is to aggregate data over thousands, millions or even billions of documents you don't need to scroll over them at all, you simply create an [aggregation query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html) and that's it, no need to retrieve documents to aggregate data, that's the whole point of aggregations, and that's also where Elasticsearch shines.

Comment: Can we use Point in time API together with aggregation? @Val

Comment: @MykhailoKramar please feel free to create a new thread explaining your use case

Comment: Link to new thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75093094/pagination-with-aggregation-in-elasticsearch @Val